# Try to trigger the event in javaScript by userinput

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Newbie for JavaScript here.  I tried to write a program that when a user types in "F" in the text, the hidden ball shows up.  However, it just does not work.   Hope someone could help me out.  Thank you in advance.
Here my html, css, js below:-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#input').on('keyup', function(){
      var textInput = $(this).val().trim.toLowerCase();
      if(textInput = "F") {
       $('#F2').trigger('click');
      }
     });
     $('#F2').on('click', function() {
      $('#F2').show();
     });
    });
```

```css
 #F2{
        width: 10px;
     height: 10px;
     background: #ccc;
     border: 2px solid #ccc;
     border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .not_shown {
     display: none;
     }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="code.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="code_js.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div id = "ball">
      <input type="text" id="input">
      <div id = "F2" class = "not_shown"></div>
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `if(textInput = "F") ` should be `if(textInput == "F") `

Comment: Check this link:-http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_trigger.asp

Comment: as others have pointed out in their answers, apart from operand bug in your conditional if statement, the condition will never evaluate to `true`.

also, capturing on `keyup` provides additional considerations.. because modifiers and other control characters that do no change the value will fire off the event.

Comment: @Mahi answer, which performs a console.log depicts that last consideration.. but that isn't really the scope of the issue of your question.. you should, however, consider it a potentially issue, particularly if you're going to be triggering other events.

Comment: actually.. it seems `keydown` is capturing control keys as well, not sure if that is something that has altered over the years.. seems like browsers didn't capture those on `keydown` or `keypress` in the past...weird

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done it here. Hope this helps.

```js
// if you do not care whether the 'F' is capital or simple
/*$('#input').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == '70') {
    $('#ball').addClass('shown');
  } else {
    $('#ball').removeClass('shown');
  }
});*/

// if you care whether 'F' is capital or simple
$('#input').keyup(function() {
  if ($('#input').val() == 'F') {
     $('#ball').addClass('shown');
  } else {
    $('#ball').removeClass('shown');
  }
});
```

```css
.ball {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: none;
}

.ball.shown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="input" type="text">
<div id="ball" class="ball"></div>
```

Also the issue with your code is that

```
if(textInput = "F")
```

needs to be

```
if(textInput == "F")
```

as in comparison and you should change

```
$(this).val().trim.toLowerCase();
```

to

```
$(this).val()
```

When you change the value to lowercase you will never have 'F' for a value, it will always be 'f'.

One more thing, I have used another approach here, not triggering a click event as you have done. I think of this as a much cleaner approach to achieve what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you.  I think your solution is very neat!

Answer (score 3):

this code is error,you should use like this `var textInput = $(this).val().trim();`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#input').on('keyup', function(){
        var textInput = $(this).val().trim();
      console.log(textInput)
        if(textInput == "F") {
            $('#F2').trigger('click');
        }
    });
    $('#F2').on('click', function() {
        $('#F2').show();
    });
});
```

```css
#F2{
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.not_shown {
    display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="code.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="code_js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "ball">
        <input type="text" id="input">
        <div id = "F2" class = "not_shown"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why make it case insensitive? seems to improperly scope the issue.

Comment: @BrettCaswell Sorry,I just copy this code from the issue.I will modify it to currect.

Comment: I was partially incorrect here.. I didn't realize OP was already making it case-insensative with `toLowerCase()` usage.. your implementation has as much merit and his intention.. but @Murat specified both the issues in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#input').on('keyup', function(){
        var textInput = $(this).val().trim();
        if(textInput == "F") {
          console.log(1);
            $('#F2').trigger('click');
        }
    });
    $('#F2').on('click', function() {
        $('#F2').show();
    });
});
```

```css
#F2{
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.not_shown {
    display: none;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="code.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id = "ball">
        <input type="text" id="input">
        <div id = "F2" class = "not_shown"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: note that it will fire off if you press any ctrl key here (like shift, while the value is `"F"`)

Comment: @BrettCaswell i think OP need that because he was using trim method .

Comment: potentially, yea... but that needs to be apparent...this snippet guarantees it will fire this event twice.. shift + f .. release f (fires).. release shift (fires)..

Answer (score 1):

1)You turned it into lower case; but in if statement, you specified upper F

2)If statement is wrong.Take a look the following one

```
if(textInput == "f")
```

This is the true if statement.